# How to check for blank space within a text file

Tags: java, arrays

CURRENT CODE:

```
String y = getLine();
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            try {
                String[] tokens = y.split("= ");
                if (tokens.length > 1 && !tokens[1].isEmpty()) {
                    dogInfo.add(tokens[1]);
                }
                y = getLine();
                System.out.println(dogInfo.get(i));
            } catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                System.out.println("Nothing here!");
            } catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e ) {
                System.out.println("Nothing here!");
            }
        }
```

I am trying to read a file as follows:

- Sex = male
- Colour =
- Age = 4
- Location = dallas

I want add anything after "= " into an arraylist called dogInfo but if there is black space after "= " then I do not want anything added to the arraylist dogInfo

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How do I check if there is nothing after the equals and space, and if there is nothing, do not add it to the arraylist dogs.

Comment: What's wrong with the code you have? Does it not work?

Comment: Yeah it's not working

Comment: Do you get an error? Not desired output? If so please  [edit] your question to include the error/expected and actual output

Comment: wouldn't it be at least easier to understand the code if using regex to match instead to split? and you should not use exceptions for *normal* control flow (they should be exceptions)... just check the index

Answer (score 1):

You add an `if` to test if the token is empty. Change this

```
dogs.add(tokens[1]);
y = getLine();
System.out.println(dogs.get(i));
```

to something like (you should also test the array length)

```
if (tokens.length > 1 && !tokens[1].isEmpty()) {
    dogs.add(tokens[1]);
    System.out.println(tokens[1]);
}
y = getLine();
```

The `!` means "not".

Comment: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException still receiving these

Comment: @jonathon For the sake of argument, I don't believe you. Prove it! Edit your question into a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: you know, if `tokens[1]` is the last one, it will never be empty - `split`, with one argument, does *ignore* trailing empty strings...